# PDF loads on computer but downloads on mobile

Tags: pdf, mobile, mobile-website, web-testing

I have my resume hosted on [resume.momohossa.in](http://resume.momohossa.in)

My issue is that when I try to reach this site on my computer, it just opens in a new page. However, when I try to open it on my phone, it has to download the file. Then, I have to open the downloaded file on a PDF viewer such as adobe. I would like for it to not immediately download on my phone. Does anyone have any advice?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

By default, on iOS devices, its safari browser can view PDF file directly, and for android deveices, its chrome browser also can do that.

make sure you pdf file is not a stream output file. just make it a static file, e.g. http://host/target.pdf not http://host/pdf/target

Comment: How do I make sure of this?

Comment: My main goal is for users that go to resume.momohossa.in to be served the pdf found at root/Momo_Hossain_resume.pdf automatically.  It looks like embedding into the HTML forces a download of the file to be viewed elsewhere, even on Chrome for android.

I would like for it to be a seamless download experience like the one that can be found here: http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf

Comment: I can see the pdf on my device(iPhone 7 14.2) both safari and chrome. [snapshots](https://postimg.cc/gallery/0yXVHht)